# How to add date range filter to sub-query in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, subquery, date-range

I tried to create a report to get sales and collection data for a particular date range. But I received some data which are not belongs to that date period. How to solve this? Here my query

```
select a.DocDate as 'Order Date',f.DocDate as 'Collection Date',b.LineTotal as 'fbsales amount',a.SlpCode,a.CardCode,b.DocEntry,
sum(case when e.TaxCode = 'NBT2' then cast(e.LineTotal as decimal(22,8)) /1.02 
when e.TaxCode = 'N2+V15' then (cast(e.LineTotal as decimal(22,8)) /1.173)  
when e.TaxCode = 'VAT8' then (cast(e.LineTotal as decimal(22,8)) /1.08) else e.LineTotal end  ) as 'fbdwnp without vat',b.LineNum
from ORDR a
left join RDR1 b on b.DocEntry = a.DocEntry
left join OSLP c on c.SlpCode = a.SlpCode
left join OITM d on d.ItemCode = b.ItemCode
left Join (select TaxCode,LineTotal,BaseEntry,BaseLine,DocEntry from DPI1 where [TargetType]<>'14') e on e.BaseEntry = b.DocEntry and e.BaseLine = b.LineNum
left Join (select DocEntry,DocDate From ODPI where CANCELED = 'N' and DocDate between '20190101' and '20191231') f on f.DocEntry = e.DocEntry
where a.CANCELED = 'N' and d.U_Product_Type = 'Facebook'  and a.DocDate between '20190101' and '20191231' and a.SlpCode = 68
group by c.SlpName,a.SlpCode,b.LineTotal,d.DocEntry,a.CardCode,c.SlpName,b.DocEntry,a.DocDate,b.LineNum,f.DocDate
```

Highlighted row of following pic should only display 'fbsales amount' but it displays 'fbdwnp withoit vat' amount also.Because sales date is 30.12.2019 and collection date is 09.01.2020.

What can i do to overcome this issue

[image]

Comment: The d.U_Product_Type condition the WHERE clause makes that LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. If you want true LEFT JOIN, move that condition to the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
and a.DocDate is not null
```

to the query